# Как называется такой выпадающий текст?

Tags: html, css, терминология

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это же ведь верстается не как выпадающий список?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется collapsible или accordion:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  document.querySelector("div").classList.toggle("hide")
}

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a>Облась по которой нужно нажать что бы развернуть</a>
<div class="hide">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 4):

Вот, пример с анимациями разворачивания.
Добавил комментарии в JavaScript.

Тут происходит анимация за счёт `transition`

В CSS свойство `height` может анимироваться через `transition` только если его задать в px.
Т.е., если у элемента будет стоять `transition: height 0.2s linear`, и мы ему будем менять свойство `height` с auto на 0, то не будет анимации. Поэтому здесь нужен JavaScript, чтобы просто задавать эту высоту в пикселях

```js
const accordion__items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__item')]; // Получаю элементы .accordion__item

accordion__items.forEach((item) => { // прохожусь по ним в цикле
  const btn = item.querySelector('.accordion__header__img'); //Нахожу у элемента кружок, в котором будет плюс или минус
  const text = item.querySelector('.accordion__text__wrapper'); // Нахожу обертку у элемента, которую буду уменьшать
  let height; // Высота обертки элемента
  resize(); // Вызываем просчёт высоты и задаём CSS стили для обёртки

  if (!item.classList.contains('active')) { // если у текущего элемента аккордеона нету класс .active
    text.style.height = '0px';  // задать обертке нулевую высоту
  }

  function addOrRemoveHeight(height) {
    if (item.classList.contains('active')) { // если у текущего элемента аккордеона есть класс .active
      text.style.height = height + 'px'; // задать высоту, которую мы просчитали перед этим в переменной height
    } else {
      text.style.height = '0px'; // Иначе задать нулевую высоту
    }
  }

  function resize() {
    text.style.height = 'auto'; // Задать элементу высоту auto, чтобы мы могли её посчитать, потому что мы её могли обнулить в CSS стилях
    height = text.scrollHeight; // Запоминаем высоту элемента в переменную
    addOrRemoveHeight(height); // Вызываем функцию, которая добавляет в CSS высоту элементу
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize); // ставим слушатель события resize на функцию resize

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => { // при клике на кружок, выполнять анонимную функцию
    item.classList.toggle('active'); // удаляем класс .active если он есть, иначе добавляем
    addOrRemoveHeight(height); // Вызываем функцию, которая добавляет в CSS высоту элементу
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&family=Raleway:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

:root {
  --red: #ff0036;
  --transitionDuration: 0.2s;
  --transitionTimingFunction: linear;
  --time: var(--transitionDuration) var(--transitionTimingFunction);
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.accordion {
  --gray: #e7e7e7;
}

.accordion__item {
  --backgroundColor: #f7f7f7;
}

.accordion__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid var(--gray);
  user-select: none;
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
}

.accordion__header__title {
  padding-right: 10px;
  transition: color var(--time);
}

.accordion__item.active {
  height: 152;
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion__header__title {
  color: var(--red)
}

.accordion__header__img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--gray);
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion__header__img-circle {
  border: 1px solid #505050;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: border-color var(--time);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion__header__img-circle {
  border-color: var(--red);
}

.accordion__header__img-circle::before,
.accordion__header__img-circle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #505050;
  transition: background-color var(--time), transform var(--time);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion__header__img-circle::before,
.accordion__item.active .accordion__header__img-circle::after {
  background-color: var(--red);
}

.accordion__item.active .accordion__header__img-circle::before {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion__header__img-circle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion__text {
  border: 1px solid var(--gray);
  border-top: none;
  padding: 12px;
}

.accordion__text__wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  transition: height var(--time);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__item active">

      <div class="accordion__header">
        <div class="accordion__header__img">
          <div class="accordion__header__img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__header__title">Who is creativia</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__text__wrapper">
        <div class="accordion__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et dolor justo. Phasellus eu ligula ac nisl volutpat tincidunt. Vestibulum vitae rhoncus odio Fusce sed enim erat. Mauris dictum lorem eu tortor porta placerat. Suspendisse ac vestibulum eros.
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .accordion__item -->

    <div class="accordion__item">

      <div class="accordion__header">
        <div class="accordion__header__img">
          <div class="accordion__header__img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__header__title">Experiences</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__text__wrapper">
        <div class="accordion__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et dolor justo. Phasellus eu ligula ac nisl volutpat tincidunt. Vestibulum vitae rhoncus odio Fusce sed enim erat. Mauris dictum lorem eu tortor porta placerat. Suspendisse ac vestibulum eros.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .accordion__item -->

    <div class="accordion__item">

      <div class="accordion__header">
        <div class="accordion__header__img">
          <div class="accordion__header__img-circle">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__header__title">Learn more</div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__text__wrapper">
        <div class="accordion__text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et dolor justo. Phasellus eu ligula ac nisl volutpat tincidunt. Vestibulum vitae rhoncus odio Fusce sed enim erat. Mauris dictum lorem eu tortor porta placerat. Suspendisse ac vestibulum eros.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- .accordion__item -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек)

Comment: @алексей добавил комментарии, думаю станет понятно

Comment: @МихаилКамахин насколько я понял автор спрашивал про то `что это такое` и `как называется`, а Вы ушли в сторону как сделать анимированный аакардеон

Comment: Как же я ненавижу, когда что-то ме-е-е-едленно выползает. Сразу ощущение, что авторы сайта/программы не умеют оптимизировать и у них всё тормозит. | Простите, наболело. Понимаю, что это модная тенденция, но выбешивает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поставил 0.2s :)

Answer (score 3):

На чистом `CSS`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkg6zwmt/1/)

Суть идеи заключается в том, чтобы спрятать чекбокс и менять его состояние путем клика на заголовок одной из строк. Чекбокс в свою очередь выступает в роли переключателя содержимого, если он `:checked`, то показываем элемент, в обычном состоянии просто скрываем через `max-height: 0` и `visibility: hidden`. Почему именно `max-height: 0` ? Потому-что только так можно анимировать высоту контента без `JS`'a. Т.к. мы не знаем максимальную высоту, мы укажем максимально допустимую для этого контента, то есть `max-height: 1000px`.

Про анимацию высоты на `css` сказано в этой статье: [how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.accordion__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 70%;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px #f6f6f6;
  padding: 20px;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row input {
  display: none;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row input:checked ~ section {
  max-height: 1000px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.5s 0s, opacity 0.5s, max-height 0.5s;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row input:checked ~ label .arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row label {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row label .icon, .accordion__container .accordion__row label .arrow {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row label .icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row label .arrow {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row label .name {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row section {
  max-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.5s 0s, opacity 0.5s, max-height 0.5s;
}
.accordion__container .accordion__row section .image {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion__container">
    <div class="accordion__row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accordion__1">
        <label for="accordion__1">
            
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/478/478544.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="name">
                <h4>Statistics</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div class="arrow">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/318/318225.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </label>
        <section>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://i2ds.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/503930-636173965766935316-16x9-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, excepturi molestias sapiente molestiae culpa sequi laudantium nihil minus voluptates modi eius, corporis hic nulla, ab laboriosam voluptatem esse. Quaerat, nostrum.
                <br>
                <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, sint numquam iure.
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__row">
        <input type="checkbox" id="accordion__2">
        <label for="accordion__2">
            
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/558/558346.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="name">
                <h4>Inbox</h4>
            </div>
            
            <div class="arrow">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/318/318225.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </label>
        <section>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://i2ds.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/503930-636173965766935316-16x9-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, excepturi molestias sapiente molestiae culpa sequi laudantium nihil minus voluptates modi eius, corporis hic nulla, ab laboriosam voluptatem esse. Quaerat, nostrum.
                <br>
                <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, sint numquam iure.
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: страшно, вырубай!

Comment: По такой же схеме можно сделать и с помощью `radio` и тогда при открытии одного, остальные открытые будут закрываться.